# Image Path incorrect when displaying HTML from database in a Razor View in MVC4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

If have some HTML which is stored in the Database. I am rendering the HTML using the below code in my view File.

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Content.ToString())
```

This is working fine except one problem, the image paths are not getting rendered properly. In my HTML(which is stored in the database) the image is defined as:

```
<img src="~/images/logo.png" />
```

But while is is rendered in the HTML it is attaching the URL of the website before the path due to which the images are not being displayed.

```
http://www.hostname.com/~/images/logo.png
```

Please comment in case any other information is required.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: How are you injecting the images in the HTML and to the db?

Comment: From the FCK Editor I am storing the HTML to the database and then rendering it in the View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normally Razor which interprets the `"~/images/"` and translates this into a relative path.  Because you are rendering the HTML yourself (in `Model.Content.ToString()`) then you are skipping this feature.

If you need to store the HTML in the database, you probably should not use the `~/images/` syntax.  If you will always publish your application at the root of a site, then just use `/images/` instead (e.g. www.mysite.com/images rather than www.mysite.com/myapp/images)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there a better way to handle this? I am storing the HTML from the FCK Editor to the database and then rendering it in the View.

Comment: If your requirement is to store HTML in the database, then there is no easy alternative.  If you don't actually need more functionality, stick with the simple solution!